# I am trying to have a different background music for each view controller in Swift 3

Tags: swift

Trying to make view controllers to have different number of loops but music is only playing once in all view controllers.

Music Helper Code:

```
import AVFoundation

class MusicHelper1 {
static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper1()


func playBackgroundMusic(fileName: String, withExtenstion fileExtension: String,withExtenstion numberOfLoops:Int) {

    do {
        AVPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)!))

        AVPlayer1.prepareToPlay()

        AVPlayer1.play()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}

func stopBackgroundMusic(fileName: String, withExtenstion fileExtension: String) {


        AVPlayer1.stop()

}
```

}

and my second view controller code:

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class Numbers: UIViewController {

```
let soundFilenames = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10" ]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    for sound in soundFilenames {
        do {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)

        }

        catch
        {

            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())

        }
    }

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tag = sender.tag
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[tag]
    audioPlayer.play()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    MusicHelper1.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic(fileName: "number", withExtenstion: "wav", withExtenstion: -1)


        }
```

}

What should I do?

Comment: Hi CJ Hutchison...thanks for your response.....however I am only using Swift 3, not sprite kit. Is there a way to do it in Swift 3?

Comment: still waiting for responses....My project is held up due to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's currently written, it looks like a variable scope issue. Your `viewWillAppear()` first accesses the global singleton `MusicHelper1.sharedHelper` to call `.stopBackgroundMusic()`, which is good. But then you create a new AVAudioPlayer using:

```
var AVPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
```

So `AVPlayer1` is a local variable, scoped to within the `viewWillAppear()` method. When `viewWillAppear()` ends, that variable goes out of scope. Since there are no more references to it, it quickly gets garbage collected and the music stops.

Since you already have a `playBackgroundMusic` function in your `MusicHelper1` class, I recommend just calling that instead.

Also, tangentially, I suggest moving the code you're using to create your list of `audioPlayers` from `viewWillAppear()` to `viewDidLoad()`, so it only happens once (when the view first loads instead of every time it appears).

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. I tried the code you advised. The first song stopped as i pressed the button but my new song stops before the view actually appears. What should I do?

Comment: @KunalKapoor How long is your song? The new view controller should appear almost instantly. If you post the code you're using, maybe I can help.

Comment: The song is not very long....may be about 1 minute......I need this coding for background music in view controllers. I also have buttons in my second view controller and need to get a sound played every time i press which is working fine

Comment: import AVFoundation
class MusicHelper1 {
    static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper1()
   var AVPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
    func playBackgroundMusic() {
do {
            AVPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "music", ofType: "wav")!))
            AVPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1
            AVPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            AVPlayer1.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }
    func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        AVPlayer1.stop()
       }}

Comment: and in second view controller

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { super.viewWillAppear(animated)
MusicHelper1.sharedHelper.stopBackgroundMusic()
var AVPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
do {AVPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:"number",ofType:"wav")!))AVPlayer1.prepareToPlay()AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops=-1AVPlayer1.prepareToPlay()AVPlayer1.play()} catch {print(error)}for sound in soundFilenames {do {
 let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")

Comment: let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
}catch
{
audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
 }
 }
}

Comment: @KunalKapoor I suggest you edit your question to include this code along with a description of the specific behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I have edited the question as suggested. Could you please see what should I do. I am new here so sorry about the mess.

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: @KunalKapoor Updated answer.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your response. I thought of using the Music Helper file for Background music as well an I can create an array to call the different music files but how do I specify which Background music is for which view controller? I mean for buttons I used a function called Did Tap and tagged the buttons. How do I tag view controllers and use them?

Comment: @KunalKapoor Easiest way would be to change 'playBackgroundMusic' to accept a resource name, then just pass the name of the song you want to play.

Comment: Hi Robert, Sorry I am new to Swift. Could you please help me with changing the code on playBackgroundMusic()? Do I return a value? How do I go about that in this case? Could you please write a sample code?

Comment: @KunalKapoor I suggest you work through Apple's excellent tutorial, "[Start Developing iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/)" to get a feel for how things are done in Swift.

Comment: thanks for that. I surely will go through that tutorial. You have been a great help. However, I need to finish my project and only thing which is not done yet, is background music code. Could you please provide me sample code on how to change playBackgroundMusic to accept a resource name and passing on song name? It would be highly appreciated

Comment: I was able to figure out the code myself. However, now the problem is either all background music are running infinitely when I set value as -1 or only once when I set value as 0. How do I go about making background music on one view to run infinitely and others only once?

Comment: You have been a great help on this question. I just need to sort out how to make one view music infinite and one view to run only once. Could you please help?

Comment: @KunalKapoor I am happy to help. What have you tried since last night?

Comment: I update the play background music function in music helper as func playBackgroundMusic(fileName: String, withExtenstion fileExtension: String)

Comment: the problem is now background music for all views only plays the number of times i specify. If i change for one, it changes for others too.....how do i solve this?

Comment: @KunalKapoor Do you think you could modify playBackgroundMusic() so it takes numberOfLoops as an argument?

Comment: I updated the playBackgroundMusic () as  func playBackgroundMusic(fileName: String, withExtenstion fileExtension: String,withExtenstion numberOfLoops:Int) but still music only runs once on all view controllers even though I specified -1 in couple of view controllers as value. Do I need to change something in this?    AVPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)!). I am not sure on how to change this.

Comment: @KunalKapoor The code in your comment looks fine. Can you update your question with the complete current code?

Comment: I have updated the question as requested. Not sure why it isn't changing when I put the value as -1.

Comment: @KunalKapoor Look at playBackgroundMusic() again. It accepts numberOfLoops as an argument, but it never sets AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops to match.

Comment: that is what I am not sure of how to implement. I tried AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops(numberOfLoops:fileExtension) but got an error, also tried AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops(numberOfLoops) but still got an error. How and where do I call the value to match? Do I need to change something here - AVPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)!) I am learning a lot with your help but not sure how to call this value and where.

Comment: @KunalKapoor AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops is a variable. You can set it with an "=". If you look back at your previous edit, you already had a line setting it to -1, which was removed.

Comment: I tried AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops= numberOfLoops(numberOfLoops:fileExtension) and AVPlayer1.numberOfLoops= numberOfLoops(Int) but got an error. What should I put on right hand side of the assignment operator to make this work? Setting an integer value was easy but it makes all view controller to play music that many times.

Comment: @KunalKapoor You're passing an integer to playBackgroundMusic() when you call it, right? So you should have that Int available as a variable within the function. The name of the variable is determined by the name of the argument.

Comment: @KunalKapoor Great!